Traer el registro correcto de un select con HTML, PHP y MySQL
Necesito hacer una modificación de provincias, donde tengo que traer la provincia en sí y el país a la que pertenece, ya que eso también debería poder ser actualizado.  No encuentro la manera de indicarle la opción seleccionada.  Este es el código que escribí:
<?php 
$id=$_REQUEST["id"];
$sql2="SELECT * FROM provincias WHERE id='$id'";
$result2=mysqli_query($conexion, $sql2);
$row2 = mysqli_fetch_array($result2);
?>

<?php
    $paises = 'select * from paises';
    $id_pais = $conexion->query($paises);
?>


<form action="provincias_modificar.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="paises_modificar">

    <label for="provincia">Provincia:</label>
    <input type="hidden" id="id" name="id" value="<?php echo $row2['id']; ?>">
    <input type="text" id="provincia" name="provincia" value="<?php echo $row2['provincia']?>" required><br><br>

    <select name="id_pais" id="id_pais">
    <?php
      if ($id_pais->num_rows > 0) {
        // Mostrar los datos en el combo desplegable
        while($rowgpais = $id_pais->fetch_assoc()) {
            echo '<option value="' . $rowgpais["id"] . '">' . $rowgpais["pais"] . ' </option>';
        }
    } else {
        echo '<option value="">No hay opciones disponibles</option>';
    } ?>
    </select><br><br>

    <input type="submit" name="Modificar" value="Modificar Provincia">

</form>

Desde ya, muchas gracias.

Pero cual es el problema?

Si lo que buscas es que se cargue el país cuando se selecciona una provincia, el primer error es que no filtras los países por provincias. Y no creo que sea muy recomendable usar select *, cuando lo único que necesitas es un select con dos campos.

Lo que necesito es hacer una modificación de provincia, tengo que poder modificar el nombre de la provincia y el país al que pertenece.  Para modificar el nombre de la provincia lo hago en un input text, y para modificar el pais con un combo select, pero no se como hacer para que me traiga el país que ya está seleccionado.

Lo resolví de la siguiente manera:
    <form action="provincias_modificar.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="paises_modificar">

    <label for="provincia">Provincia:</label>
    <input type="hidden" id="id" name="id" value="<?php echo $row2['id']; ?>">
    <input type="text" id="provincia" name="provincia" value="<?php echo $row2['provincia']?>" required><br><br>

    <label for="id_pais">País:</label>
    <select name="id_pais" id="id_pais">
    <?php
        if ($result_paises->num_rows > 0) {
            // Mostrar los datos en el combo desplegable
            while($row_pais = $result_paises->fetch_assoc()) {
                $selected = $row2['id_pais'] == $row_pais['id'] ? 'selected' : '';
                echo '<option value="' . $row_pais['id'] . '" ' . $selected . '>' . $row_pais['pais'] . '</option>';
            }
        } else {
            echo '<option value="">No hay opciones disponibles</option>';
        }
    ?>
    </select><br><br>

    <input type="submit" name="Modificar" value="Modificar Provincia">

</form>

Saludos!
